# Laravel: Can I get DB request as indexed array

Tags: database, laravel

I've met a problem wit Laravel DB query.
I have to use something like:

```
$priceList = DB::select("exec dataBase.dbo.PRICELIST ?", [$id]);
```

But I can't directly access server.
As it tries to return associative array it fails to return anything.
Does enyone know how to return indexed array from this in Laravel?

**EDIT:**

I'm receiving data from stored procedure not table

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: So, you need indexed array of the $priceList data ?

Comment: @SagarGautam I need $priceList to be indexed, but DB query runs out of memory because exec returns indexed array, but Laravel tries to make associative array from it

Answer (score 0):

I think, that your problem is connected with wrong using of laravel DB methods.
try this:

```
$priceList = DB::table('table_name')->where('id', $id)->get();
// if you need to get array(instead of Collection instance) just use
$priceList = DB::table('table_name')->where('id', $id)->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: I'm not reading data from table, I'm receiving it from stored procedure using "exec"